# How do i include spaces in my RegEx in java?

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

I am trying to make it so the user can enter 07XXXXXXXXX or 07XXX XXXXXX, both should work, but my RegEx seems to not be working correctly

I have tried adding \\d, \\s, \\w and none of that has worked

My code is:

```java
//The space should be between {3} and [0-9]
while (!Scanner.hasNext("07[0-9]{9} | 07[0-9]{3} [0-9]{6}")) {

    System.out.println("\nThe mobile number you have entered is not valid.\nIt should start with 07 and should contain 9 additional digits.");

    Scanner.nextLine();
} //end while
```

The program should accept both 07XXXXXXXXX and 07XXX XXXXXX, but when i try and include the space, it doesn't accept either option.

"07[0-9]{9}" works for 07XXXXXXXXX on its own, but when I add "| 07[0-9]{3} [0-9]{6}", neither option works.

Comment: Remove the spaces next to the pipe, otherwise they're considered part of the regex.

Comment: `hasNext(regex)` tests single *token*. Since default delimiter os one-or-more-whitespaces then if there is space in your data then only first part will be tested so regex will not be able to match second part. Maybe you want to change default delimiter to line separator (like `useDelimiter("\\R")` which will make Scanner consider *lines* as tokens (you can change it back later).

Comment: But IMO easier way to write it would be something like `String number = null; do{ number = scanner.nextLine(); }while(!number.matches("07[0-9]{3}\\s?[0-9]{6}");`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow the space with a ? question mark it will mean "zero or one of" the space

```
07[0-9]{3} ?[0-9]{6}
```

You can also use number pairs in brackets to give a range:

```
07[0-9]{3} {0,1}[0-9]{6}
```

If you plan to allow other characters like hyphen you can make a character class for those. This allows space, hyphen or dot:

```
07[0-9]{3}[-. ]{0,1}[0-9]{6}
07[0-9]{3}[-. ]?[0-9]{6}
```

I recommend you put hyphen first in a character class as it can be taken to mean "range" like you have with 0-9. By putting it first it doesn't define a range. Also a period  normally means "any character" but inside a character class it loses this special meaning and is literally just a period

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. This will make it 07XXX XXXXXX?

Comment: the [-. ] works with - or . but does not work with a space?

Comment: Are you asking or telling? By putting a question mark after the space it means "zero or one" of the space, ie it makes the space optional. You can use `\s` also for white space, just in case the space you're typing isn't the same kind of space the code is expecting - are you typing a non breaking space when the regex  is looking for a breaking space? Etc

Comment: Are you using some sort of flag on the regex engine to "ignore white space in the pattern"? I know c# regex engine can do that

Comment: I used that and typed it 07123 123123 and it didn't work, but 07123456789 works and I've only used what you have said, nothing else

Comment: In a blank class with none of my other code in it, it still doesn't work

Comment: I added some screenshots showing it working for java, I don't have any more suggestions as to why it's not working - perhaps post the whole new mini test program you wrote, as a new question so we can see exactly what youre doing